# Browser scrolling versus in page scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, osx-lion

I'm using OSX Lion and Chrome which allows you to swipe back and forth to go back/ forward in the browser. However I'm finding it often interferes with scrolling within a page. I have horizontal scroll bars within the website i'm creating and swiping back and forth within them often causes the browser to move forward/ backward in my browse history - definitely not the behaviour i want.

I'm creating my horizontal scroll boxes very simply with html/css and the overflow property. I'm wondering if the correct approach is to use javascript to detect a scroll event, and prevent the default behaviour. It just seems like a more complicated approach to something that should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

http://cubiq.org/iscroll

http://www.azoffdesign.com/plugins/js/overscroll

http://uxebu.com/blog/2010/09/15/touchscroll-0-2-first-alpha-available/

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jScrollTouch

Tried or seen any of these, you can just disable the browser scrollbars and use these instead..

Comment: Don't be silly. Browser features are disabled everyday by high and small sites. Both for security and brand indentity.

Comment: how do you disable the swipe scrolling (between pages) in mac lion though? I haven't been able to do it...

Comment: Mark my answer and ill post it.

Comment: *Finish* your answer and then it can be accepted. Don't use extortion to get answers accepted.

Comment: The answer I found was to use the following: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"> and apply overflow:x-hidden to body css tag. sorry dad. :/